# Activity declared in AndroidManifest but got error: Unable to find explicit activity class

Tags: android, android-activity, android-manifest

I'm trying to build an app using [TabGroupChildDemo][1] as a template but I got the following errors:

```
11-12 15:02:23.189: E/AndroidRuntime(699): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-12 15:02:23.189: E/AndroidRuntime(699): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.lupradoa.lakari/com.lupradoa.lakari.Inicio_TabGroup}: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.luisprado.lakari/com.luisprado.lakari.InicioActivityGroup}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
11-12 15:02:23.189: E/AndroidRuntime(699):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
11-12 15:02:23.189: E/AndroidRuntime(699):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
11-12 15:02:23.189: E/AndroidRuntime(699):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
11-12 15:02:23.189: E/AndroidRuntime(699):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
11-12 15:02:23.189: E/AndroidRuntime(699):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-12 15:02:23.189: E/AndroidRuntime(699):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-12 15:02:23.189: E/AndroidRuntime(699):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
11-12 15:02:23.189: E/AndroidRuntime(699):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-12 15:02:23.189: E/AndroidRuntime(699):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-12 15:02:23.189: E/AndroidRuntime(699):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
11-12 15:02:23.189: E/AndroidRuntime(699):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
11-12 15:02:23.189: E/AndroidRuntime(699):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-12 15:02:23.189: E/AndroidRuntime(699): Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.luisprado.lakari/com.luisprado.lakari.InicioActivityGroup}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
11-12 15:02:23.189: E/AndroidRuntime(699):  at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1541)
11-12 15:02:23.189: E/AndroidRuntime(699):  at android.app.ActivityThread.resolveActivityInfo(ActivityThread.java:1870)
11-12 15:02:23.189: E/AndroidRuntime(699):  at android.app.LocalActivityManager.startActivity(LocalActivityManager.java:285)
11-12 15:02:23.189: E/AndroidRuntime(699):  at android.widget.TabHost$IntentContentStrategy.getContentView(TabHost.java:694)
11-12 15:02:23.189: E/AndroidRuntime(699):  at android.widget.TabHost.setCurrentTab(TabHost.java:358)
11-12 15:02:23.189: E/AndroidRuntime(699):  at android.widget.TabHost.addTab(TabHost.java:236)
11-12 15:02:23.189: E/AndroidRuntime(699):  at com.lupradoa.lakari.Inicio_TabGroup.onCreate(Inicio_TabGroup.java:68)
11-12 15:02:23.189: E/AndroidRuntime(699):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
11-12 15:02:23.189: E/AndroidRuntime(699):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
11-12 15:02:23.189: E/AndroidRuntime(699):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
11-12 15:02:23.189: E/AndroidRuntime(699):  ... 11 more
```

I've searched the mistake, changed things to check if activities showed  (they did), checked Stackoverflow, the internet... with no result.

The app AndroidManifest (I've tried removing the package name and I got the same error.
):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.lupradoa.lakari"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
    <permission
        android:name="com.lupradoa.com.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.lupradoa.com.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
              android:required="true"/>


    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
               android:value="xxxx"/>
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="4030500" />


        <activity
            android:name="com.lupradoa.lakari.SplashScreen"

            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/FullscreenTheme" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
            <activity android:name="com.lupradoa.lakari.Inicio_TabGroup" android:label="@string/app_name">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
            <activity android:name="com.lupradoa.lakari.Inicio" android:label="@string/app_name"/>
            <activity android:name="com.lupradoa.lakari.Galeria" android:label="@string/app_name"/>
            <activity android:name="com.lupradoa.lakari.Marcas" android:label="@string/app_name"/>
            <activity android:name="com.lupradoa.lakari.Noticias" android:label="@string/app_name"/>
            <activity android:name="com.lupradoa.lakari.InicioActivityGroup" android:label="@string/app_name">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
            <activity android:name="com.lupradoa.lakari.MarcasActivityGroup" android:label="@string/app_name"/>
            <activity android:name="com.lupradoa.lakari.GaleriaActivityGroup" android:label="@string/app_name"/>
            <activity android:name="com.lupradoa.lakari.NoticiasActivityGroup" android:label="@string/app_name"/>
            <activity android:name="com.lupradoa.lakari.BrandOneActivity" android:label="@string/app_name"/>
            <activity android:name="com.lupradoa.lakari.BrandTwoActivity" android:label="@string/app_name"/>

        </application>

</manifest>
```

SplashScreen:

```
package com.lupradoa.lakari;


import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

import com.lupradoa.lakari.util.SystemUiHider;


/**
 * An example full-screen activity that shows and hides the system UI (i.e.
 * status bar and navigation/system bar) with user interaction.
 * 
 * @see SystemUiHider
 */
public class SplashScreen extends Activity {
    /**
     * Whether or not the system UI should be auto-hidden after
     * {@link #AUTO_HIDE_DELAY_MILLIS} milliseconds.
     */
    private static final boolean AUTO_HIDE = true;

    /**
     * If {@link #AUTO_HIDE} is set, the number of milliseconds to wait after
     * user interaction before hiding the system UI.
     */
    private static final int AUTO_HIDE_DELAY_MILLIS = 3000;

    /**
     * If set, will toggle the system UI visibility upon interaction. Otherwise,
     * will show the system UI visibility upon interaction.
     */
    private static final boolean TOGGLE_ON_CLICK = true;

    /**
     * The flags to pass to {@link SystemUiHider#getInstance}.
     */
    private static final int HIDER_FLAGS = SystemUiHider.FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION;

    /**
     * The instance of the {@link SystemUiHider} for this activity.
     */
    private SystemUiHider mSystemUiHider;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_screen);

        //launch app
        Button go = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonGo);
        go.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent begin = new Intent (SplashScreen.this, Inicio_TabGroup.class);
                startActivity(begin);

            }
        });


        final View controlsView = findViewById(R.id.fullscreen_content_controls);
        final View contentView = findViewById(R.id.fullscreen_content);

        // Set up an instance of SystemUiHider to control the system UI for
        // this activity.
        mSystemUiHider = SystemUiHider.getInstance(this, contentView,
                HIDER_FLAGS);
        mSystemUiHider.setup();
        mSystemUiHider
                .setOnVisibilityChangeListener(new SystemUiHider.OnVisibilityChangeListener() {
                    // Cached values.
                    int mControlsHeight;
                    int mShortAnimTime;

                    @Override
                    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR2)
                    public void onVisibilityChange(boolean visible) {
                        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR2) {
                            // If the ViewPropertyAnimator API is available
                            // (Honeycomb MR2 and later), use it to animate the
                            // in-layout UI controls at the bottom of the
                            // screen.
                            if (mControlsHeight == 0) {
                                mControlsHeight = controlsView.getHeight();
                            }
                            if (mShortAnimTime == 0) {
                                mShortAnimTime = getResources().getInteger(
                                        android.R.integer.config_shortAnimTime);
                            }
                            controlsView
                                    .animate()
                                    .translationY(visible ? 0 : mControlsHeight)
                                    .setDuration(mShortAnimTime);
                        } else {
                            // If the ViewPropertyAnimator APIs aren't
                            // available, simply show or hide the in-layout UI
                            // controls.
                            controlsView.setVisibility(visible ? View.VISIBLE
                                    : View.GONE);
                        }

                        if (visible && AUTO_HIDE) {
                            // Schedule a hide().
                            delayedHide(AUTO_HIDE_DELAY_MILLIS);
                        }
                    }
                });

        // Set up the user interaction to manually show or hide the system UI.
        contentView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (TOGGLE_ON_CLICK) {
                    mSystemUiHider.toggle();
                } else {
                    mSystemUiHider.show();
                }
            }
        });

        // Upon interacting with UI controls, delay any scheduled hide()
        // operations to prevent the jarring behavior of controls going away
        // while interacting with the UI.
        findViewById(R.id.buttonGo).setOnTouchListener(
                mDelayHideTouchListener);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Trigger the initial hide() shortly after the activity has been
        // created, to briefly hint to the user that UI controls
        // are available.
        delayedHide(100);
    }

    /**
     * Touch listener to use for in-layout UI controls to delay hiding the
     * system UI. This is to prevent the jarring behavior of controls going away
     * while interacting with activity UI.
     */
    View.OnTouchListener mDelayHideTouchListener = new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            if (AUTO_HIDE) {
                delayedHide(AUTO_HIDE_DELAY_MILLIS);
            }
            return false;
        }
    };

    Handler mHideHandler = new Handler();
    Runnable mHideRunnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mSystemUiHider.hide();
        }
    };

    /**
     * Schedules a call to hide() in [delay] milliseconds, canceling any
     * previously scheduled calls.
     */
    private void delayedHide(int delayMillis) {
        mHideHandler.removeCallbacks(mHideRunnable);
        mHideHandler.postDelayed(mHideRunnable, delayMillis);
    }
}
```

Inicio_TabGroup, where the tabs and navigation stack is built:

```
package com.lupradoa.lakari;

import android.app.TabActivity;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Bitmap.Config;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode;
import android.graphics.PorterDuffXfermode;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.graphics.RectF;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TabHost;
import android.widget.TabHost.OnTabChangeListener;
import android.widget.TabWidget;
import android.widget.TextView;



@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public class Inicio_TabGroup extends TabActivity implements OnTabChangeListener
{ 
 private static final String[] TABS = { "InicioActivityGroup", "MarcasActivityGroup", "NoticiasActivityGroup","GaleriaActivityGroup" };
 private static final String[] TAB_NAMES = { "Inicio", "Marcas", "Noticias","Galeria"};
 public static TabHost tabs ;
    public static TabWidget tabWidget ;    
 protected Bitmap roundedImage;
    public boolean checkTabsListener = false;


    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle)
    {        
     super.onCreate(icicle);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Bitmap roundedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.ic_tab_background);
        roundedImage = getRoundedCornerBitmap(roundedImage,3);

        tabs = getTabHost();

        tabWidget = tabs.getTabWidget();

     tabs.setOnTabChangedListener(this);

     for (int i = 0; i < TABS.length; i++)
        {
         TabHost.TabSpec tab = tabs.newTabSpec(TABS[i]);

         //Asociating Components
         ComponentName oneActivity = new ComponentName("com.luisprado.lakari", "com.luisprado.lakari." + TABS[i]);
         Intent intent = new Intent().setComponent(oneActivity);           
         intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
         tab.setContent(intent);         
         //Setting the Indicator
         MyTabIndicator myTab = new MyTabIndicator(this, TAB_NAMES[i],(i+1), roundedImage); 
         tab.setIndicator(myTab); 
         tabs.addTab(tab);
        }

     checkTabsListener = true;

        for(int i=0;i<tabs.getTabWidget().getChildCount();i++)
        {
         tabs.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        }


  tabs.getTabWidget().getChildAt(0).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_tab_background);   

  //Maintaining Clicks

  // Home Tab Click
  tabWidget.getChildAt(0).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {   
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v)
   {     
     if(InicioActivityGroup.InicioActivityStack != null && InicioActivityGroup.InicioActivityStack.mIdList.size()>1)
     {      
      InicioActivityGroup.InicioActivityStack.getLocalActivityManager().removeAllActivities();
      InicioActivityGroup.InicioActivityStack.mIdList.clear();
      InicioActivityGroup.InicioActivityStack.mIntents.clear();
      InicioActivityGroup.InicioActivityStack.mAnimator.removeAllViews();
      InicioActivityGroup.InicioActivityStack.startChildActivity("ShopInfoActivity", new Intent(InicioActivityGroup.InicioActivityStack, Inicio.class));

     }

     tabWidget.setCurrentTab(0);
     tabs.setCurrentTab(0);
     tabs.getTabWidget().getChildAt(0).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_tab_background);  
   }
        });

  // Marcas tab Click

  tabWidget.getChildAt(1).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {   
   public void onClick(View v)
   {     
    if(MarcasActivityGroup.MarcasActivityStack != null && NoticiasActivityGroup.NoticiasActivityStack.mIdList.size()>0)
    {
     MarcasActivityGroup.MarcasActivityStack.getLocalActivityManager().removeAllActivities();
     MarcasActivityGroup.MarcasActivityStack.mIdList.clear();      
     MarcasActivityGroup.MarcasActivityStack.mIntents.clear();
     MarcasActivityGroup.MarcasActivityStack.mAnimator.removeAllViews();            
     MarcasActivityGroup.MarcasActivityStack.startChildActivity("TrackingGroupActivity", new Intent(MarcasActivityGroup.MarcasActivityStack, Marcas.class));           
    }     

    tabWidget.setCurrentTab(1);
    tabs.setCurrentTab(1);
    tabs.getTabWidget().getChildAt(1).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_tab_background);       
   }
        });

  // Noticias tab click

  tabWidget.getChildAt(2).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {   
   public void onClick(View v)
   {     
    if(NoticiasActivityGroup.NoticiasActivityStack != null && GaleriaActivityGroup.GaleriaActivityStack.mIdList.size()>0)
    {

    NoticiasActivityGroup.NoticiasActivityStack.getLocalActivityManager().removeAllActivities();
    NoticiasActivityGroup.NoticiasActivityStack.mIdList.clear();      
    NoticiasActivityGroup.NoticiasActivityStack.mIntents.clear();
    NoticiasActivityGroup.NoticiasActivityStack.mAnimator.removeAllViews();            
    NoticiasActivityGroup.NoticiasActivityStack.startChildActivity("NewsActivityGroup", new Intent(NoticiasActivityGroup.NoticiasActivityStack, Noticias.class));           
    }     

    tabWidget.setCurrentTab(2);
    tabs.setCurrentTab(2);
    tabs.getTabWidget().getChildAt(2).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_tab_background);       
   }
        });

  //Galeria tab click
  tabWidget.getChildAt(3).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
  {   
      public void onClick(View v)
        {     
          if(GaleriaActivityGroup.GaleriaActivityStack   != null && GaleriaActivityGroup.GaleriaActivityStack.mIdList.size()>0)
          {

              GaleriaActivityGroup.GaleriaActivityStack.getLocalActivityManager().removeAllActivities();
              GaleriaActivityGroup.GaleriaActivityStack.mIdList.clear();      
              GaleriaActivityGroup.GaleriaActivityStack.mIntents.clear();
              GaleriaActivityGroup.GaleriaActivityStack.mAnimator.removeAllViews();            
              GaleriaActivityGroup.GaleriaActivityStack.startChildActivity("GalleryActivityGroup", new Intent(GaleriaActivityGroup.GaleriaActivityStack, Galeria.class));           
          }     

          tabWidget.setCurrentTab(3);
          tabs.setCurrentTab(3);
          tabs.getTabWidget().getChildAt(3).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_tab_background);       
        }
    });
   }


    public class MyTabIndicator extends LinearLayout      
    {
  public MyTabIndicator(Context context, String label, int tabId, Bitmap bgImg)
  {
   super(context);
   LinearLayout tab = null;
   TextView tv;
   this.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

   if(tabId == 1)
   {
    tab = (LinearLayout) LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.inicio_tab, null);
    tv = (TextView)tab.findViewById(R.id.tab_label);
    tv.setText(label);
   }



   else if(tabId == 2)
   {
    tab = (LinearLayout) LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.marcas_tab, null);
    tv = (TextView)tab.findViewById(R.id.tab_label);
    tv.setText(label);
   }
   else if(tabId == 3)
   {
    tab = (LinearLayout) LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.noticias_tab, null);
    tv = (TextView)tab.findViewById(R.id.tab_label);
    tv.setText(label);
   }
   else if (tabId == 4)
   {
       tab = (LinearLayout) LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.galeria_tab, null);
       tv = (TextView)tab.findViewById(R.id.tab_label);
       tv.setText(label);
   }       
   this.addView(tab, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(320/4,55));   
  }  
    }



 public void onTabChanged(String tabId) 
 {      
  InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(tabs.getApplicationWindowToken(), 0);

        for(int i=0; i<tabs.getTabWidget().getChildCount(); i++)
  {                             
         if(tabId.equalsIgnoreCase(TABS[i]))
   {            
    tabs.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_tab_background);     
   }
   else
   {
    tabs.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).setBackgroundColor((Color.TRANSPARENT));
   }     
    }  
 }

  public static Bitmap getRoundedCornerBitmap(Bitmap bitmap,float roundPxRadius)
 {
        Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(output);

        final int color = 0xff424242;
        final Paint paint = new Paint();
        final Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());
        final RectF rectF = new RectF(rect);
        final float roundPx =roundPxRadius;

        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
        paint.setColor(color);
        canvas.drawRoundRect(rectF, roundPx, roundPx, paint);

        paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.SRC_IN));
        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, rect, rect, paint);

        return output;
 }

 public void onResume()
 {
  super.onResume();


  //ReConstructing TabViews
  reDesignTabViews(); 
 }

 public void onPause()
 {
  super.onPause();     
 }




 /**
  * Method used to re constructing the Views at tab bar. This solves tabs disappearing issue.
  */
 public void reDesignTabViews()
 {
  MyTabIndicator myIndicator;


  //Construction of tab views....
  for(int i=0 ; i< tabWidget.getChildCount() ; i++)
  {
   myIndicator = (MyTabIndicator) tabWidget.getChildAt(i);
   myIndicator.removeAllViews();

   switch (i) 
   {

     case 0:
     myIndicator.addView((LinearLayout) LayoutInflater.from(getApplicationContext()).inflate(R.layout.inicio_tab, null));
     break;
    case 1:    
     myIndicator.addView((LinearLayout) LayoutInflater.from(getApplicationContext()).inflate(R.layout.marcas_tab, null));    
     break;
    case 2:    
     myIndicator.addView((LinearLayout) LayoutInflater.from(getApplicationContext()).inflate(R.layout.noticias_tab, null));
     break;
    case 3:
        myIndicator.addView((LinearLayout) LayoutInflater.from(getApplicationContext()).inflate(R.layout.galeria_tab,null));
     break;

   }   
  }  
 }

}
```

This class opens InicioActivityGroup to control navigation through activities showing the tabs.

```
package com.lupradoa.lakari;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.lupradoa.lakari.util.AnimatedActivity;

public class InicioActivityGroup extends AnimatedActivity {
    public static InicioActivityGroup InicioActivityStack;
     @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
        {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            InicioActivityStack = InicioActivityGroup.this;

           startChildActivity("InicioActivityGroup", new Intent(this, Inicio.class));
        }
}
```

Could you please help me?

Comment: Note that activities-in-tabs has been deprecated for nearly three years. Please use more modern solutions: action bar tabs, `ViewPager` with a tabbed indicator, `FragmentTabHost`, etc.

Comment: @CommonsWare I know it and there are plenty of "SuppressWarnings..." Where can I get a tutorial to build an app where tabs are always visible ?

Comment: `FragmentTabHost` is the current stock solution for always-visible tabs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `onCreate` method of `Inicio_TabGroup` you have mentioned package name as `com.luisprado.lakari`

```
//Asociating Components
             ComponentName oneActivity = new ComponentName("com.luisprado.lakari", "com.luisprado.lakari." + TABS[i]);
             Intent intent = new Intent().setComponent(oneActivity);           
             intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
             tab.setContent(intent);
```

Instead package name should be `com.lupradoa.lakari` right? Since `InicioActivityGroup` is defined in package `com.lupradoa.lakari`.

```
//Asociating Components
             ComponentName oneActivity = new ComponentName("com.lupradoa.lakari", "com.lupradoa.lakari." + TABS[i]);
             Intent intent = new Intent().setComponent(oneActivity);           
             intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
             tab.setContent(intent);
```

Comment: @Luis Post a new question with the modified code and the new error

Comment: Thanks! I made the move to fragments :)